# How to change files extension with bat

Tags: batch-file

I need to change files extension in folders and subfolders by creating bat file

Example

File1.txt
File2.txt
.........
FileN.txt

Should be renamed to

File1.jpg
File2.jpg
File3.jpg 
.........
FileN.jpg

inside the folder and in subfolders.

Additionally then

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
.........
FileN.txt
```

should be removed

I have tried `for /d /r %f in (.) do ren "%f\*.txt" "*.jpg"` but it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I have created new file and this is helped me

```
@echo off
  pushd C:\exmasconv
     for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d/b/s *.txt') do ren "%%i" "%%~ni.jpg"
  popd
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use "rename". For example:

rename *.jpg *.txt

OR

rename "test123.txt" "123.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Try this (test it on some test files first!):

```
REN File*.txt File*.jpg
```